# Webpack - error when merging configuration

Tags: web-part, react, typescript, build, webpack

I'm having following urgent error when trying to execute npm run dev command:

```
'import("c:/Projects/myProject/node_modules/@types/webpack/index").Configuration' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("c:/Projects/myProject/node_modules/@types/webpack-merge/node_modules/webpack/types").Configuration'.
  Types of property 'cache' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean | object | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FileCacheOptions | MemoryCacheOptions | undefined'.
      Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FileCacheOptions | MemoryCacheOptions | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

I have three webpack files (webpack.common.ts, webpack.dev.ts, webpack.prod.ts)
I import configuration from webpack.common.ts and try to merge with webpack.dev.ts

Code for webpack.dev.ts:

```
import merge = require('webpack-merge');
import common from "./webpack.common";
const SPSaveWebpackPlugin = require('spsave-webpack-plugin');
import webpack = require('webpack');
import globals from "./Constants";
import credentials from './spsave-credentials';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new SPSaveWebpackPlugin({
      "coreOptions": {
        "checkin": true,
        "checkinType": 1,
        "siteUrl": globals.ScriptUrl
      },
      "credentialOptions": credentials.dev,
      "fileOptions": {
        "folder": globals.ScriptPath
      }
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = merge(common, config);
```

Error is showing on last line, common is underlined and above is the error.

Code for webpack.common.ts:

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const glob = require('glob');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

import globals from "./Constants";
import { buildConfig } from "./src/config/buildConfig";
const chalk = require('chalk');
const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  entry: {},
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, globals.DistributionDirectory),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: `${globals.ScriptUrl}/${globals.ScriptPath}/`
  },
  externals: [
    require('webpack-require-http')
  ],
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/i, use: 'raw-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.(s)?css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars-loader", exclude: /node_modules/, options: {
          knownHelpersOnly: false,
          helperDirs: [
            path.join(__dirname, './src/templates/handlebars-helpers')
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              emitFile: true,
              name: 'img/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
          loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: "./src/lib/dccs.frms.tpl.engine.js",
      to: "lib/dccs.frms.tpl.engine.js"
    }], { writeToDisk: true })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  }
};

//#region Automatic webparts configuration

const WEBPARTS_ROOT = "web-parts"; // root folder for webparts in project structure
const contentEditorWebParts = glob.sync('src/web-parts/**/index.ts').map((webPartUrl: any) => {
  const webpartName = path.basename(path.dirname(webPartUrl));
  return {
    name: webpartName,
    dirname: path.dirname(webPartUrl),
    entry: {
      name: `${WEBPARTS_ROOT}/${webpartName}/${webpartName}`,
      src: `./${webPartUrl.split(path.sep).join("/")}`
    }
  };
});

contentEditorWebParts.forEach((webpart: any) => {
  const isEnabled = buildConfig.webparts.includes(webpart.name);
  if (isEnabled) {
    let webPartConfiguration: webpack.Entry = {};
    webPartConfiguration[webpart.entry.name] = webpart.entry.src;
    config.entry = Object.assign({}, config.entry, webPartConfiguration);

    if (typeof config.plugins !== 'undefined')
      config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        {
          filename: `${webpart.entry.name}.html`,
          template: `./${webpart.dirname}/template.html`,
          inject: false,
          minify: true,
          // define some extra properties for injection in html
          globals: globals, // globals defined in Constants.ts, Usage in html: <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.globals.ContainerId %>
          associatedJsFilename: `${globals.ScriptUrl}/${globals.ScriptPath}/${webpart.entry.name.split(".")[0]}.js?v=${globals.Version}`,
        }
      )]);
  } else {
    console.log(chalk.yellow(`Skipping: ${webpart.entry.name} from automatic webpack web parts build. Please check /src/config/buildConfig.ts`));
  }
});

//#endregion

//#region Automatic templates configuration
const TEMPLATE_ROOT = "templates";
const templates = glob.sync("src/templates/**/*.html").map((templateUrl: string) => { // i.e. src/templates/Schichtplanaenderung/Schichtplannderungen_SPAESchichtplanaenderung.html
  const filename = templateUrl.substring(templateUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // i.e. Schichtplannderungen_SPAESchichtplanaenderung.html
  const filenameWithoutExtension = filename.split(".")[0];
  const dirname = path.dirname(templateUrl); // i.e. src/templates/Schichtplanaenderung
  const templateName = path.basename(dirname); // i.e. Schichtplanaenderung

  return {
    name: templateName,
    dirname: dirname,
    filename: filename,
    entry: {
      name: `${TEMPLATE_ROOT}/${templateName}`,
      src: `./${dirname}/${templateName}.ts`
    }
  };
});

templates.forEach((template: any) => {
  const isEnabled = buildConfig.templates.includes(template.name);
  if (isEnabled) {
    let tplConfiguration: webpack.Entry = {};
    tplConfiguration[template.entry.name] = template.entry.src;
    config.entry = Object.assign({}, config.entry, tplConfiguration);

    if (typeof config.plugins !== 'undefined')
      config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        {
          filename: `templates/${template.filename}`,
          template: `./${template.dirname}/${template.filename}`,
          inject: false,
          minify: true,
          // define some extra properties for injection in html
          associatedJsFilename: `${globals.ScriptUrl}/${globals.ScriptPath}/templates/${template.name.split(".")[0]}.js?v=${globals.Version}`,
          title: 'Title of Page2',      // Usage in html: <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>
          globals: globals              // globals defined in Constants.ts, Usage in html: <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.globals.ContainerId %>
        }
      )]);
  } else {
    console.log(chalk.yellow(`Skipping: ${template.entry.name} from automatic webpack templates build. Please check /src/config/buildConfig.ts`));
  }
});
//#endregion

//#region JSLink automatic configuration
const jsLinkFiles = glob
  .sync("src/scripts/jsLink/**/*.ts")
  .map((jslinkUrl: string) => {
    const fileName = jslinkUrl.substring(jslinkUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    const filenameWithoutExtension = fileName
      .split('.')
      .slice(0, -1)
      .join('.');
    const dirname = path.dirname(jslinkUrl);
    // const templateName = path.basename(dirname);

    return {
      name: filenameWithoutExtension,
      dirname: dirname,
      filename: fileName,
      entry: {
        name: `jslink/${filenameWithoutExtension}`,
        src: `./${dirname}/${fileName}`
      }
    };
  });

jsLinkFiles.forEach((jslinkFile: any) => {
  const isEnabled = buildConfig.jslink.includes(jslinkFile.name);
  if (isEnabled) {
    let jslinkConfig: webpack.Entry = {};
    jslinkConfig[jslinkFile.entry.name] = jslinkFile.entry.src;
    config.entry = Object.assign({}, config.entry, jslinkConfig);
  }
  else {
    console.log(chalk.yellow(`Skipping: ${jslinkFile.entry.name} from automatic webpack templates build. Please check /src/config/buildConfig.ts`));
  }
});
//#endregion

export default config;
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.ts",
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.ts",
    "spserver": "node spserver/server.js",
    "devServer": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "yeoman-generator",
    "sharepoint",
    "classic",
    "generator"
  ],
  "author": "person",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@pnp/common": "^1.3.2",
    "@pnp/logging": "^1.3.2",
    "@pnp/odata": "^1.3.2",
    "@pnp/sp": "^1.3.2",
    "@types/handlebars": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.8",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/sharepoint": "^2016.1.2",
    "@types/toastr": "^2.1.37",
    "@types/webpack-merge": "^4.1.5",
    "@uifabric/fluent-theme": "^7.1.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.19.0",
    "decamelize": "^2.0.0",
    "es6-map": "^0.1.5",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.7",
    "handlebars": "^4.1.2",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^1.1.5",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "mobx": "^4.13.1",
    "mobx-react": "^6.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-gyp": "^4.0.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-core": "^10.1.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.38.0",
    "officedev-sharepoint-core": "^1.0.13",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.61",
    "raw-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "spsave-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "thenby": "^1.3.4",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "ts-loader": "^5.4.3",
    "uppercamelcase": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "webpack-require-http": "^0.4.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "yeoman-generator": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.14.5",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.4.27",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5",
    "chalk": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typedoc": "^0.14.2",
    "typedoc-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "app"
  ]
}
```

I don't have any idea what to do about it and I need to build the project. Help would be very much appreciated.
What is weird, it seems that to my collegue this is working and npm run dev is executing without issue